# Paginação cakephp

Tags: cakephp, paginação

No meu controller eu seto o `limit` para 7, mas quando ele faz a paginação, a primeira página vem com 3, 4, 1, e vai variado.

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 7,
);
```

É isso que faço no meu controller, tenho que fazer algo a mais?